# Склеить массив с переходом на новую строку от первого элемента

Tags: c#

Основываясь на инфу с этого сайта https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59217/merging-two-arrays-in-net

```
int[] front = { 1 };//данные в массиве изменил для простоты...
int[] back = { 5, 6, 7, 8 };
int[] combined = front.Concat(back).ToArray();
```

в результате будет так:

```
1
5
6
7
8
```

Но как быть если нужен такой результат:

```
15
16
17
18
```

Не прибегая к двум форичам ?

Comment: какой должен быть вывод, если в `fron` несколько элементов? Могут ли в первом массиве быть элементы больше 10?

Comment: @Grundy больше 10 - нет. Мне нужен вывод только с одним элементом

Comment: Создайте массив длинной `front.length * back.length` и занесите все значение через лямда выражение в приращении. Должно получится через 1 `foreach()`.

Comment: тогда front нужно делать просто числом, и можно будет есть использовать в Select: `int[] combined = back.Select(b=> front*10 + b).ToArray();`

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Ядро</sub>

```
var combined = new int[front.Length * back.Length];

for (var i = 0; i < front.Length; i++)
    for (var j = 0; j < back.Length; j++)
        combined[i * back.Length + j] = front[i] * 10 + back[j];
```

<sub>Вывод</sub>

```
for (var i = 0; i < front.Length; i++)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < back.Length - 1; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(combined[(i * back.Length + j)].ToString("D2"));
        Console.Write(' ');
    }

    Console.Write(combined[(i * back.Length + back.Length - 1)].ToString("D2"));
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

<sub>Оптимизированный вывод</sub>

```
var buf = new char[2];

for (var i = 0; i < front.Length; i++)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < back.Length - 1; j++)
    {
        var num = combined[(i * back.Length + j)];

        if (!num.TryFormat(buf, "D2")) { /*throw*/ }

        Console.Write(buf);
        Console.Write(' ');
    }

    var num = combined[(i * back.Length + back.Length - 1)];

    if (!num.TryFormat(buf, "D2")) { /*throw*/ }

    Console.Write(buf);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```